# FluentBootstrap - Acces to the form object from partial views

Tags: fluentbootstrap

I have a view that renders a form with code similar to the following:

```
@using( var form = Bootstrap.Form().SetHorizontal( 3 ).AddCss( Css.ColSm8, Css.ColMdOffset2 ).Begin() )
{
     @form.DisplayFor( m => m.Name )
     // bla bla bla
     @Html.Action( "Details", "Fare", new { entity = Model.FareId } )
}
```

How can I access the `form` object in the partial view, so that the same layout is applied to the whole form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of work was spent ensuring that the Bootstrap control stack would carry-over into partial views. You have two options here:

- The first is to just pass the `form` object to the partial/action as part of the model. In your case, you would just add it as another property in the anonymous model object you're sending to the action.
- You don't need to use the `form` instance to make FluentBootstrap recognize you're in a form. It's just a convenience to make calling the extensions appropriate to a form easier. You can also just call something like `Bootstrap.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)` right from the global Bootstrap object in your partial and it will respect any settings you've placed in the containing form defined in the containing view.

Comment: It worked perfectly!
Especially the second option made eveything very easy.

Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :)